# Parse.com CurrentUser always null

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parse-platform

Recently i'm trying to write some apps in C#. I used Parse.com for few of my iOS apps, everything worked fine and i loved it.

Now i'm trying to write ASP.NET web app with C# that is also using Parse.com.

It seems that ParseUser.CurrentUser is always null. In my Controller i call for Model method - Login() and then use CheckUser() to establish if anyone is logged in.

```
//Controller

public bool Index()
{
    LoginModel login = new LoginModel();
    Task t = Task.Run(() =>{
        login.Login();
    });
    t.Wait();
    return login.CheckUser();
}
```

In my model i have two methods:

```
//Model

public async void Login()
{
    await ParseUser.LogInAsync("admin", "admin");
    Debug.WriteLine(ParseUser.CurrentUser.Username);//actually outputs username
}

public bool CheckUser()
{
    if (ParseUser.CurrentUser != null) //always says false
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It seems that my mistake is inside Index method and probably has something to do with asynchronous login method.How can i handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not block on async code as Stephen Cleary point out [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

The gist of the article is that the different task handling models use different contexts. So when the TPL tries to return to an async context, it can not find it.

Further, by wrapping your async call in a task, and waiting on the task, does not mean you are also waiting for the wrapped async call to return.

I would re-write the Index method like so :

```
public async Task<bool> Index()
{
    LoginModel login = new LoginModel();
    await login.Login();
    return login.CheckUser();
}
```